# KnockoutJS and conditional custom binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have custom KnockoutJS data binding which looks like

```
<a class="btn single ok" title="OK" tabindex="5" 
   data-bind="command: loginUser, 
   css: { disabled: !userSelected(), 'no-disabled': userSelected()}">OK</a>
```

Is there any way to make `command` binding conditional as well so when `!userSelected()` then is not executed? Or do I need to that conditional in the command creation code?

Comment: Once the binding is in the `data-bind` attribute, there's no way to skip its `init` from being executed (as far as I know). You can however pass some `null` or empty value: `command: userSelected() ? loginUser : null`.

Comment: @user3297291 You have just confirmed what I thought. At that point I will need to check it at the `loginUser` command code.

Comment: what is the "command", i don't get it... what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @MKougiouris Custom binding. I have updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have ended up to checking for `userSelected()` state in the `loginUser` function.